# Find database source

Tags: database

I start off by apologizing if this is a dumb question but I know nothing about databases.

There is a website that gets item prices from an auction in a game called Eve Online and I'm curious how would I find out where they sourced the data from the auction, e.g. https://eve-marketdata.com/price_check.php?type_name_header=Tritanium

my intention is to make a little app that figures out when to buy and sell popular items for myself based on the trends being set in the auction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to apologize, your question isn't dumb :)

Apps like this usually go through some sort of API to retrieve information from a provider.

In the case of EVE Online they have their own [developer portal](https://developers.eveonline.com) which is quite well documented. Including resources, guidelines and instructions on how to build basic apps.

While I can't tell you what specific database they accessed for the information, the relevant API/data access points will be in that portal somewhere.

Hope this helps!